# Running Invoke-Command on remote machine

Tags: invoke-command

I am trying to run any command I want on a remote machine.  Example:  gpupdate /force or copy file1 to file2 etc...  so I have this code:

```
$ComputerName = Read-Host "Enter a remote computer name"
$RemoteCommand = Read-Host "Enter a remote command to run:  Example   gpupdate /force"

$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {$RemoteCommand}
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { $? }
```

It runs without error and in fact it returns TRUE.  But the file I have in c:\temp never gets copied to c:\temp\tmp

why not?

Comment: ok, I can get it to work but not with a $variable for my command line.   If I hard code what I want to run on the remote machine it works.

Comment: Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {cmd /c dir > c:\temp\dir.txt}  #  this works
    Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {$RemoteCommand}   # this does not work

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are passing a string variable to Invoke-Command in the scriptblock, which just evaluates to the content of the string. You are not passing it a scriptblock with actual commands.
To illustrate the difference see this code:

```
# Output is just the content of the string
$commandString = "Get-Service spooler"
Invoke-Command {$commandString}

# Output is the result of the commandlet
$scriptBlock = {Get-Service spooler}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

To get the result you want you can use the `[scritpblock]` accelerator, like this:

```
# Output is the result of the commandlet invocation defined in the string
$commandString = "Get-Service spooler"
$scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($commandString)
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the script like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { powershell.exe -Command "$RemoteCommand"}
```

If you get problems with escaping characters, there is also the -encodedCommand switch. From the powershell help:

```
# To use the -EncodedCommand parameter:   
$command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```